# lex and yacc file build with main method in yacc file and not in lex file

Tags: c, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

Hi i am trying to compile code from lex and yacc book by John R. Levine
in the book the instructions for compiling are for unix below

We called our various lexers chl-N.l, where TVcorresponded to a particular
lex specification example. Similarly, we called our parsers chl-M.y, where
again Mis the number of an example. Then, to build the output, we did the
following in UNIX:

```
lex chl- n.l
yacc -d chl- m.y
cc -c lex.yy.c y.tab.c
cc -o example- m. n lex.yy.o y.tab.o -11
```

which obviously won’t work.

The .l file has no main function and .y has main function when i try to compile the .l file it gives error of winmain WinMain@16. is there any workaround for it using EditPlus IDE??
please reply soon
I have windows 10(64-bit) i have installed flex,bison,and trying to compile through ide
the code link is below
i am trying to compile files ch1-06.l ch1-06y ch1-06.h in prog.zip provided with book.
http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565920002/progs.zip

Comment: I really don't understand the procedure you followed. It does not seem possible that you did "... in UNIX" and ended up with a Windows error. And the command `lex chl- n.l` is meaningless: is it a copy-and-paste error? Are we supposed to guess what you filled in? Please *edit your question* to be more precise.

Comment: There is no inherent problem in the `main()` function being in the `.y` file instead of the `.l`.  Both are converted to C source files by their corresponding tool, and you simply have to use both C files together to build the executable.  It sounds like you are trying to build a separate executable from each source, which will indeed fail.